# Probability of sending correct message problem

Tags: probability

We are sending 1s and 0s. And there is a 10% chance that the wrong number is sent so we send the number 3 times and the opposing party takes the majority of the 3 tries to be the correct message. What is the probability that we send the wrong message?

My Answer: P(Wrong message) = P(we send a wrong number twice) + P(we send a wrong number thrice)= $(1/10)^3 + (1/10)^2(9/10) = 0.01$ but the answer is apparently 0.028.

Thank You

Comment: You forgot that there are three ways to sent 2 out of three numbers wrong. So the $(1/10)^2(9/10)$ needs to be multiplied by 3. Then you will get 0.028

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom 32$ ways of getting $2$ out of the $3$ tries incorrect so the answer should be 
$$\binom 31 \left(\frac1{10}\right)^3+\binom 32\left(\frac1{10}\right)^2\left(\frac9{10}\right)=0.028$$

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 way to send the 3 messages correctly each time with probability .9 * .9 * .9

There is 1 way to send the 3 messages incorrectly each time with probability .1 * .1 * .1

There are 3 ways to send the 3 messages with one mistake, because the mistake can happen either on the first, second, or third attempt. Each of those ways has probability .1 * .9 * .9.

There are 3 ways to send the 3 messages with two mistakes, each with probability .1 * .1 * .9.

So, the solution is (3 * (.1 * .1 * .9)) + (.1 * .1 * .1) = .028